# ios 5 storyboard : navigate through detail view items without returning to master table

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I am using storyboards to accomplish the following :

i have a master view which contains a table view with several items.
My master view is embedded in a navigation controller. My master view has a subclass "MasterViewController"

I then have a detail view. This is not embedded in a navigation controller. My detail view has a subclass "DetailViewController";
I have a segue between my table cell and the detail view.

Clicking on an item in my masterview table pushes to the detailview.

I want then to be able to navigate through my masterview table items inside my detailview without returning to the masterview.
I have a "prev" and a "next" button but what should be the actions for these buttons?

I've only started with objective c and xcode since 2 weeks so i'm still a noob with this...
Thanks for your help.

I've read somewhere that i should be doing something like this :

```
// Just remove the current 
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:FALSE];

// Create a new 
DetailViewController* newcontroller = [DetailViewController alloc] init];

// init detailview object ....

[self.navigationController pushViewController:newcontroller animated:FALSE];
```

but this code just brings me back to the master view...

**UPDATE :**

Ok i've managed to navigate inside detail view but when clicking the next item all my outlets are gone???

This is the code for my "next" button:

```
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    // fetch next object and pass it to the new detailviewcontroller
    detailViewController.detailItems = self.detailItems;

    UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

    // Pop this controller and replace with another
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    [navController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];
```

executing the code above pops the detail view and pushes to a new detail view. But now i only have an empty detail view...
Inside the viewdidload method of my detailview i've set a NSLOG to print my detailitems object and it shows fine the next object but none of my labels are visible now...

Inside my viewdidload i have the following code :

```
NSString *itemName = [self.detailItems objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLOG(@"current item : %@",itemName); 
// Correctly shows the current item name
```

And also the following :

```
self.nameLabel.text = itemName;
NSLog(@"name label : %@",self.nameLabel.text);
```

But the code above only shows the labeltext when i initially push from the master view to the detail view.
Once i am inside the detail view and click the "next" button this prints :

```
name label : (null)
```

Seems like my labels somehow are gone when pushing to a new detailview ???

Please help !

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the solution myself...

Just changed 1 line :

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

I replaced the above with the code below and Bob's your uncle :

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myDetailView"];
```

"myDetailView" is the identifier of my detail view.